# Concurency celery django bulk create or update

Tags: django, python-3.x, concurrency, celery

I have a competition problem with django, I have a celery task that updates the number of users in a table. Since there are a lot of lines to update, I use a bulk update, and to avoid creating unnecessary lines, I use a bulk create.

```
all_statistic_user = StatisticsCountriesUser.objects.filter(user__in=all_branch_user,countries=user.country)
if all_statistic_user:
    all_statistic_user.update(total_users=F('total_users') +1)

all_statistic_user = StatisticsCountriesUser.objects.exclude(user__in=all_branch_user,countries=user.country)
if all_statistic_user:
    all_statistic_user = [StatisticsCountriesUser(user_id=user.id,countries=user.country) for user in all_statistic_user ]
    StatisticsCountriesUser.objects.bulk_create(all_statistic_user)
else:
    all_statistic_user = [StatisticsCountriesUser(user_id=user.id, countries=user.country) for user in all_branch_user]
    StatisticsCountriesUser.objects.bulk_create(all_statistic_user)
```

The problem is that if the task is executed asynchronously, if the tasks are executed at the same time the first task creates the user list, then the second task also retrieves the user list, the first creates or updates the users, but the second task the list no longer has the right information to update or create
. the solution I thought was to put the tasks in a synchronous list and not asynchronously is this possible? Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a good read on this topic: https://blog.daftcode.pl/working-with-asynchronous-celery-tasks-lessons-learned-32bb7495586b

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @schwobaseggl this is an interesting article indeed. But I didn't find the solution to my problem. If the task can be called x times if I get back, let's imagine 
`#task one user = user.objects.all() user.update=F('total_users') +1`
the second task is launched just before the update of task one
`#task two user = user.objects.all() user.update=F('total_users') +1`
Using task 2 will have the information before the update, where I thought it would be a synchronous task[task_one,task_two] or a completely different proposal I'm a taker

Comment: @schwobaseggl I finally succeeded by isolating my create and update bulks in atomic transactions with select_for_update. I found the answer in your article :)